# DateRow local does not change

Tags: swift, uidatepicker, eureka-forms

I'm building a FormViewController thanks to Eureka forms framework but I ran into a problem for my DateRow. I'd like the UIDatePicker to be displayed in French but months always appear in english.

I tried to set up another UIDatePicker in French on another view controller and it worked normally :

```
let date = UIDatePicker()
date.datePickerMode = .date
date.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr")
date.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 200, width: 300, height: 200)
view.addSubview(date)
```

[image: French Date Picker]

The language is changing thanks to the the UIDatePicker local property so I tried to add this property where the date picker is set in Eureka files (because i don't think we can access the Date picker in the DateRow object).

```
open class DateCell: Cell<Date>, CellType {

public var datePicker: UIDatePicker

public required init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}

required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

open override func setup() {
    super.setup()
    accessoryType = .none
    editingAccessoryType =  .none
    datePicker.datePickerMode = datePickerMode()
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(DateCell.datePickerValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    datePicker.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr")
}
```

But the date picker always stays in english.

Do you have any ideas where I should add the local line ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the `datePicker` of the `DateRow` as `cell.datePicker`. To change its locale use the `cellSetup` callback. You might also want to set the formatter of the row so that the value is displayed with the correct locale:

```
<<< DateRow(){
    $0.value = Date()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr")
    formatter.dateStyle = .long
    $0.dateFormatter = formatter
}.cellSetup({ (cell, row) in
    cell.datePicker.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr")
})
```